# Validação Input AspNetMvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Como faço para validar no Exit de um Input, já tenho a função que retorna bool, se retornar false, não posso deixar sair do Campo vendedor.snome e apresentar uma mensagem de alerta.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Editar">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="vendedor.idvendedor" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
            <input asp-for="vendedor.snome" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">E-Mail:</label>
            <input asp-for="vendedor.semail" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="datanascimento">Data de Nascimento:</label>
            <input asp-for="vendedor.ddatanascimento" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="salariobase">Salário Base:</label>
            <input asp-for="vendedor.nsalariobase" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="iddepartamento">Departamento:</label>
            <select asp-for="vendedor.iddepartamento" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.departamentos, "iddepartamento", "snome"));" class="form-control"> </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-default" />
            <a asp-action="Index">Voltar</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: usa o evento [onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur)

Comment: A função que você tem seria em javascript mesmo? Pra validar ao sair de um campo só com JS. Coloque a função que comentou na pergunta.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann, na verdade a função que tenho é no meu services, com as validações e ifs, ai minha dúvida é, se essa function que está fora da view, lá no meu Model retornar false, exibo a mensagem de alerta. Porém, não tenho ideia nem de como chamar essa function na view.. imagino que deva chamar com JS, porém, não sei como faço isso.

Comment: @RicardoPontual cheguei a ver sobre o evento, o meu problema, é não saber como fazer essa chamada, olhando pra uma function fora da view, lá meu model, onde tem minhas regras de negócio.

Comment: Services seria uma camada do seu projeto? Você parece estar misturando as coisas. Se for isso mesmo, essa validação é do backend e você deve fazer ela também, mas será chamado na sua controller em algum momento. A validação que você está pedindo na pergunta é de frontend e você deverá fazer por javascript.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann consegui encontrar documentação exatamente para o que preciso, é chamado de RemoteValidation no Asp.Net, eu crio a function na minha camada de backend, e na minha classe de atributos eu chamo parâmetro [Remote(action: "MinhaFuncao",controller: "MeuController")]

Comment: @Jd3Tecnologia Então seria legal você escrever uma resposta para que a sua pergunta e solução possa ajudar outras pessoas no futuro.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo sou novo na comunidade, obrigado pela dica, vou responder para fechar! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Validação, é chamada de RemoteValidation no Asp.Net, cria a function na camada de serviços(BackEnd, e na classe de atributos chamar parâmetro  –`[Remote(action: "MinhaFuncao",controller: "MeuController")]`